# Is it a good practice to add indexing on a boolean field in a Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Suppose we have model with boolean field:

```
class AModel(models.Model):
    flag = models.BoleanField()
```

Is there any reason to add index on this field?

I think it hasn't reason because there will be small profit in search(this only split two) but large overhead with recording. But my colleague thinks different.

Is there any rule of thumb for this?

Comment: This depends on the kind of queries you plan on doing against the database. If its a write-heavy DB then yes, the index is overkill.

Comment: Generally a index on a boolean field does not really help a lot, because it only divides the data in half. You generally wish to have an index on columns with many unique values.

Comment: There is no rule of thumb and this isn't bad practice at all. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: There is no right answer and everyone has their own rule of thumb. I say: define only indexes for fields which are "selective" or you know beforehand will be queried often. And later you can analyze the database performance and add more indexes on fields that are actually used. Generally defining many indexes in the beginning does more harm than good.

Comment: If you expect to query multiple boolean indexes in a single query wouldn't the indexes be very helpful because they compound? e.g. 3 boolean indexes divides the dataset by ~8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If you had data that has predominantly one or other of the boolean values (ie, almost everything is FALSE), but you want to commonly query only values that match the other (ie, query only for TRUE values), then an index on the boolean field could make a very big difference to performance: especially if you force the index to store the TRUE values first.

The trick there is that the field (and index) *is* selective, because you can discard most of the rows, and so the index can be used to speed this up, by storing the ones that are useful.

Alternatively, you could have an index on a different field (that you are also querying on, perhaps) that uses a `WHERE <boolean-field>` clause to *only* store the true values (or vice-versa, depending upon your needs). I haven't tried it, but I'd wager WHOLE DOLLARS that Postgres is able to use this index correctly...

Comment: "especially if you force the index to store the TRUE values first" - good point, and how would one go about doing that, in Django?

Comment: You _may_ have to create the index in a RawSQL migration. I'm not actively involved with it, but there is IIRC some current work going on that improves support for functional/expression indexes in django.